# Is there a way to add source information in static libraries similar to what can be done with .pdb?

Tags: c++, windows, static-libraries, pdb-files

If I build a dll or an exe file it is possible to embed source information into the corresponding pdb using pdpstr.exe and a [source server data block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/source-server-and-source-indexing):

```
SRCSRV: ini ------------------------------------------------
VERSION=1
SRCSRV: variables ------------------------------------------
SRCSRVVERCTRL=https
SRCSRVTRG=%var2%
SRCSRV: source files ---------------------------------------
D:\local\path\to\my\file\main.cpp*https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owner/repo/hash/main.cpp
SRCSRV: end ------------------------------------------------
```

This will make Visual Studio debugger download the source file from github when reading the pdb.

However, is it possible to add this information to a static library?

In my case I am building a static library on one build machine and then, on another build machine, using that static library to build a dll. It is easy to add source information from source code used in the dll since the build machine can get that infromation from git. But is there any good way to get the source information from the static library?

One way could be to publish static libraries with a text file that maps source code to remote version:

```
D:\local\path\to\my\static_lib\file1.cpp,https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owner/repo/hash/file1.cpp
D:\local\path\to\my\static_lib\file2.cpp,https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owner/repo/hash/file2.cpp
...
```

But I was hoping for a better solution.